# pass parameter from cs class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a web application using asp.net and I want to pass parameter form class.cs file to aspx.cs file. But I got nothing displayed or retrieved.
The following is my code:

Class.cs class:

```
public class Class1
{

     public string _time = "TIME ";


     public String _RetrievedTime(string time)
     {
           return  _time = time;
     }
 }
```

aspx.cs code:

```
    protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String f = Request.QueryString["_time"];

        //a = f.ToString();
        Class1 tmp = new Class1();
        String q;
        q = tmp._RetrievedTime(f);
        Response.Write(q);

   }
```

Could you help please to fix what is the problem or if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: What var are you trying to return from _RetrievedTime?

Comment: Can you verify that you are indeed passing `_time` in your query string and `f` has a value?

Comment: I want to retrieve String _time

Comment: can you put a break point on the line where you have "Response.Write(q)" and see the value of q?

Comment: Your `_RetrievedTime` method overrides `_time` with the parameter `time` before returning it, so you aren't fetching the stored values, you're fetching the value you just set it to.  It's simply not clear what you *want* (based on the fact that you rejected the proposed answer).

Comment: Servy could you plz tell me which parameter do I have to put inside QueryString: String f = Request.QueryString["    "];

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
 public String _RetrievedTime(string time)
 {
       return  time;
 }
```

Comment: I don't think that will solve his problem.  `return _time = time` will still return the value of `time` and also set `_time` equal to `time`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you use AJAX on your page? 
If so you'd better use some Label to test your class.

```
    protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String f = Request.QueryString["_time"];

        //a = f.ToString();
        Class1 tmp = new Class1();
        String q;
        q = tmp._RetrievedTime(f);
        Label1.Text = q;
   }
```

Put your label inside UpdatePanel and don't forget to specify your button4 as trigger for that updatepanel.